# Extract Random values from JSON using JMeter

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins

Can any one guide/help me in extracting Random set from below JSON using built-in extractor, Not custom plugin.

For example,
I need to extract random set with two values  Rid:7 and Name: Test_Kumar

```
{
    "Documents": [
        {
            "rId": 0,
            "Name": "Test_Sunil",
        }, 
        {
            "rid": 3,
            "Name": "Test_Sunil",
        }, 
        {
            "rid": 7,
            "Name": "Test_Kumar",
        }
        {
            "rid": "0",
            "Name": "Unknown",
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using [JSR223 PostProcessor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PostProcessor) and the following code:

```
def documents = new groovy.json.JsonSlurper().parse(prev.getResponseData()).Documents

def randomSet = documents.get(RandomUtils.nextInt(0, documents.size()))

vars.put('randomSet', new groovy.json.JsonBuilder(randomSet).toString())
```

Extracted value can be referred as `${randomSet}` later on where required.

More information:

- [Apache Groovy: Parsing and producing JSON](https://groovy-lang.org/processing-json.html)
- [Apache Groovy: What Is Groovy Used For?](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-groovy)

Comment: Thanks Dmitri, Is this possible to do it with out using Post Processors,  like using JMeter builtin extraction rules.

Comment: There are no "builtin extraction rules" in JMeter